# Get the relative lowest 3 levels of an array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

I have a list of items in a PHP array, and I'm trying to write a function to get the values for the relative 3 lowest levels from each array block. I could format the array hierarchically based on the **parent_id** field, but now I'd like to filter it down to the relative 3 lowest levels only.

Here is the array that I'm working with (the values are just examples):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 1,
    'parent_id' => NULL,
    'name' => 'Home',
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 3,
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Contact',
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 6,
            'parent_id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Phone',
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 7,
            'parent_id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Email',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'id' => 2,
    'parent_id' => NULL,
    'name' => 'About',
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => 4,
        'parent_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'History',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'id' => 5,
        'parent_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Team',
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => 8,
            'parent_id' => 5,
            'name' => 'John',
            'children' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'id' => 12,
                'parent_id' => 8,
                'name' => 'John 2',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          1 => 
          array (
            'id' => 10,
            'parent_id' => 5,
            'name' => 'Alex',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 9,
    'parent_id' => 22,
    'name' => 'Mary',
  ),
)
```

The PHP function I'm trying to write should result in the following output:

- **About**

  - History
  - Team

    - *John*
- **Home**

  - Contact

    - *Phone*
    - *Email*
- **Mary**

With real data, there might be more or fewer levels, so the function should be able to find the lowest levels, no matter if there are only 4 (as in this example), or 12.

I was able to write a function that returns the top 3 levels from the array, but I'm looking for a good way to return the bottom 3 levels of each array block.

Thanks for the help in advance!

**Additional context**

The original array from PHP:

```
$flat_array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'Home'),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'About'),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Contact'),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'History'),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Team'),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Phone'),
    array('id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Email'),
    array('id' => 8, 'parent_id' => 5, 'name' => 'John'),
    array('id' => 9, 'parent_id' => 11, 'name' => 'Mary'),
);
```

The function I'm transforming this with into a hierarchical array:

```
function hierarchyOrder($flat_array) {
    $resultIds = get_ids(($flat_array));
    $map = array();
    foreach ($flat_array as $arr) {
        $map[$arr['id']] = $arr;
    }
    $hierarchy = array();
    foreach ($flat_array as $arr) {
        if (($arr['parent_id'] !== null) AND (in_array($arr["parent_id"], $resultIds))) {
            $map[$arr['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$map[$arr['id']];
        }
        else {
            $hierarchy[] = &$map[$arr['id']];
        }
    }
    return $hierarchy;
}

function get_ids($flat_array) {
    return array_map(function($item) {
      return $item['id'];
    }, $flat_array);
}
```

Previously, I tried to build up the function by modifying a similar function that returns the top 3 levels of an array. My solution was not dynamic enough, and I was not able to figure out a logic that reliably can return the bottom 3 levels. My starting point was:

```
function returnCorrectLevels($input) {
  $result = [];

  foreach ($input as $item) {
      $level1 = [
          'id' => $item['id'],
          'parent_id' => $item['parent_id'],
          'name' => $item['name'],
      ];

      if (isset($item['children'])) {
          $level2 = [];
          foreach ($item['children'] as $child1) {
              $level2[] = [
                  'id' => $child1['id'],
                  'parent_id' => $child1['parent_id'],
                  'name' => $child1['name'],
              ];

              if (isset($child1['children'])) {
                  $level3 = [];
                  foreach ($child1['children'] as $child2) {
                      $level3[] = [
                          'id' => $child2['id'],
                          'parent_id' => $child2['parent_id'],
                          'name' => $child2['name'],
                      ];
                  }
                  $level2[count($level2)-1]['children'] = $level3;
              }
          }
          $level1['children'] = $level2;
      }
      $result[] = $level1;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: You should paste the array rather as code than `var_dump` result so that people could have easier time with reproducing it.

Comment: Updated the question with the original array and the function that transforms it into a hierarchical array.

Comment: Please always present your sample input as the output from `var_export()` (NOT `print_r()`) -- this way volunteers won't have to do the tedious chore of reformatting your data before they can start actually working with your data.  In your coding attempt, where are you actually keeping tract of the depth of the recursion?  ...ah wait, that is the code that creates the input data and you haven't even attempted to solve your own problem?  We should just do your job for you for free?  (Needs more effort/enthusiasm)

Comment: Yea, I took one attempt at recursive solution and quickly resigned as it's not really a problem worth solving IMO. This could be made much easier if the initial array was built in a better way. Not to mention if some more robust solutions were used, for example simple classes that would represent a tree and its children.

Comment: @mickmackusa Appreciate the feedback; I edited my question above to include the input data with var_export and the original function that I started with (that returns the top 3 levels). If you know how this can be solved by keeping track of the depth of the recursion, I'm all ears. I'm not necessarily looking for the final code as the solution, but any guidance on coming up with the logic.

Comment: Stack Overflow would not be nearly as useful if it collected "partial answers".  All answers are expected to deliver the desired result expressed in the question.  If your question is asking for too much effort from volunteers, then maybe the question's requirements need to be reduced or you should hire a developer if you can't make a coding attempt.

Comment: @Thor have you changed your sample input, but not your desired result? Is this intended? Your new data does not change the desired result?  Your "original" 2d array doesn't have a John 2.

Comment: @mickmackusa I haven't. I only tested one of the solution proposals with another level, to see if it really returns the bottom 3 hierarchy levels, which it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, as per the desired output mentioned in the question, the `parent_id` of **About** menu item has to be `null`.

```
<?php 
// Base array to arrange
$flat_array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'Home'),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'About'),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Contact'),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'History'),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Team'),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Phone'),
    array('id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Email'),
    array('id' => 8, 'parent_id' => 5, 'name' => 'John'),
    array('id' => 9, 'parent_id' => 11, 'name' => 'Mary'),
);

// Obtaining hierarchy order used from existing question
function hierarchyOrder($flat_array) {

    // Getting all parent IDs from the array
    $resultIds = get_ids(($flat_array));
   
    // empty output array 
    $map = array();

    // iterating through to get array elements
    foreach ($flat_array as $arr) {
        $map[$arr['id']] = $arr;
    }
    
    // Blank output array
    $hierarchy = array();

    // Iterating through $flat_array to get child elements
    foreach ($flat_array as $arr) {
        if (($arr['parent_id'] !== null) AND (in_array($arr["parent_id"], $resultIds))) {
            $map[$arr['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$map[$arr['id']];
        }
        else {
            $hierarchy[] = &$map[$arr['id']];
        }
    }
    
    return $hierarchy;
}

// function to get parent IDs 
function get_ids($flat_array) {
    return array_map(function($item) {
      return $item['id'];
    }, $flat_array);
}

//  assigning the final result to a variable
$result = hierarchyOrder($flat_array);
?>
<ul>
    <?php foreach($result as $item){
        echo "<li><strong>{$item['name']}</strong>";
        if(isset($item['children']) AND count($item['children']) > 0)
        {
            echo "<ul>";
                foreach($item['children'] as $child)
                {
                    echo "<li>{$child['name']}";
                    if(isset($child['children']) AND count($child['children']) > 0)
                    {
                        echo "<ul>";
                        foreach($child['children'] as $subchild)
                        {
                            echo "<li>{$subchild['name']}</li>";
                        }
                        echo "</ul>";
                    }
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        echo "</li>";
    }?>
</ul>
```

Final output will be as follows:
[Screenshot of final output as desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ormsy.jpg)

***Edited after reading the comments provided by the author***

```
<?php 
// Base array to arrange
$flat_array = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'Home'),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'About'),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Contact'),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'History'),
    array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Team'),
    array('id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Phone'),
    array('id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Email'),
    array('id' => 8, 'parent_id' => 5, 'name' => 'John'),
    array('id' => 9, 'parent_id' => 11, 'name' => 'Mary'),
    array('id' => 10, 'parent_id' => 8, 'name' => 'Kiran'),
);

// Obtaining hierarchy order used from existing question
function hierarchyOrder($flat_array) {

    // Getting all parent IDs from the array
    $resultIds = get_ids(($flat_array));
   
    // empty output array 
    $map = array();

    // iterating through to get array elements
    foreach ($flat_array as $arr) {
        $map[$arr['id']] = $arr;
    }
    
    // Blank output array
    $hierarchy = array();

    // Iterating through $flat_array to get child elements
    foreach ($flat_array as $arr) {
        if (($arr['parent_id'] !== null) AND (in_array($arr["parent_id"], $resultIds))) {
            $map[$arr['parent_id']]['children'][] = &$map[$arr['id']];
        }
        else {
            $hierarchy[] = &$map[$arr['id']];
        }
    }
    
    return $hierarchy;
}

// function to get parent IDs 
function get_ids($flat_array) {
    return array_map(function($item) {
      return $item['id'];
    }, $flat_array);
}

//  assigning the final result to a variable
$result = hierarchyOrder($flat_array);


// function to generate menu items - recursively
function prepare_menu_items($menuArray)
{
    $output = '';
    foreach($menuArray as $item){
        $output .= "<li>{$item['name']}";
        if(isset($item['children']) AND count($item['children']) > 0)
        {
            $output .= "<ul>";
            $output .= prepare_menu_items($item['children']);
            $output .= "</ul>";
        }
        $output .= "</li>";
    }
    
    return $output;
}

?>
<ul>
    <?=prepare_menu_items($result)?>
</ul>
```

The above code is accommodating `n` number of levels, picking the bottom 3 levels is bit challenging with current example given.

You can try to positively arranged if the array is sored decending from bottom to top. You can try as per my comment below.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal, I tested it, but it didn't give the desired results.

The parent_id of "About" doesn't have to be null (the array might not contain symmetrical levels in each array block, so that can't be assumed). Also, the modified input only contains 3 levels now instead of 4. When adding a 4th level under "John", the function doesn't return that anymore, so it's not returning the "lowest 3 levels" of the input array.

Comment: Sufficiently complex sample data is very important if you want to receive high quality solutions.

Comment: As per the comments given by @mickmackusa to the question, the initial array has to be reconstructed so that the followup codes dont have much of workarounds to adjust the desired output. It would be very easy to obtain bottom 3 levels if the menu item can be sorted from bottom to topmost (decending order). Finally, after manupulating in the followup code, sort the final array based on `id` before displaying.

Comment: @PracticalOpportunist The data structure and what is stored can be changed, and I'm flexible on that. If you see any other ways to achieve the same end result, let me know. But in the real data, there might be parent_ids that are not mapping to actual ids, as a user might not have access to all items. That's why I excluded storing level information in the database, as for one user, that might be true, but for another, it might not be.

Answer (score 0):

ok i fix it

```
$flat_array = array(
array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'Nikos Kontominas'),
array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'Ioanna Kontominas'),
array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 1, 'name' => 'Panagiotis Kontominas'),
array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'George Filipakos'),
array('id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 2, 'name' => 'Katina Filipakos'),
array('id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Nikos Kontominas'),
array('id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 3, 'name' => 'Elpida Kontominas'),
array('id' => 8, 'parent_id' => 5, 'name' => 'John Travolta'),
array('id' => 9, 'parent_id' => null, 'name' => 'Mary Kontominas'),
array('id' => 10, 'parent_id' => 7, 'name' => 'Katia Gianakakos'),
array('id' => 11, 'parent_id' => 10, 'name' => 'Elpida Hover'),
);


 ///////////////////////////
echo '<ul>';
returbData($flat_array);
echo '</ul>';
function returbData($arr){
$record=count($arr);    
 foreach ($arr as $item) {
    if($item['parent_id']==null){
        echo '<li>'.$item['name'];
        repeat($item['id'],$arr);
        }
    }
  }



  function repeat($item,$arr){
  echo'<ul>';
   foreach ($arr as $parent) {
    if($item==($parent['parent_id'])){
        
        echo '<li>'.$parent['name'];
        
        repeat($parent['id'],$arr);
      }
   }
   echo '</ul>';
   echo '</li>';    


}
```

and you have output page code

```
<ul>
<li>Nikos Kontominas
    <ul><li>Panagiotis Kontominas
        <ul><li>Nikos Kontominas
            <ul></ul>
            </li>
            <li>Elpida Kontominas
                <ul><li>Katia Gianakakos
                    <ul><li>Elpida Hover
                        <ul></ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Ioanna Kontominas
    <ul><li>George Filipakos
            <ul></ul>
        </li>
        <li>Katina Filipakos
            <ul><li>John Travolta
                <ul></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>Mary Kontominas
    <ul></ul>
</li>
```